# Is taking things on 'rent' be called 'shop'?

Tags: word-usage

There is an abstract paragraph talking about ski products. And, the website is all about giving ski products on rent.

There is a button after abstract clicking on which takes us to the product page. I am naming the button as 'shop now'.

So my question is: Can I say 'shop now' for the products we give on rent? I am afraid that 'shop' means to purchase a product and own it, but here it is for rent.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the word you are looking for is Hire. So, on this website, the button would be Hire Now instead of the more usual Buy Now

Comment: Good answer, although in American English one normally sees "Rent" rather than "Hire".

Answer (score 1):

To "shop" is to search for things that you may want to buy or rent. It does not necessarily imply that you are buying outright and not renting. In the U.S., anyway, people routinely talk about "shopping for an apartment", "shopping for a rental car", etc. There's a website called "shopapartments.com", where users "shop" for "apartments to rent". "shoprentone.com" is a site where users can rent (not buy) home appliances, and it has "shop" in the name as well as a "Shop Now" button. (Disclaimer: I'm not recommending either of these sites. I just found them now with a Bing search, I have no idea whether they are good companies or not.)

"Buy" or "purchase" indicates that you are taking ownership. You would not say that you are "buying a hotel room" if you mean that you are just paying to spend a night or two.

But there's no problem saying that you are "shopping" for things that you will rent. "Shop now" is fine for rental products.

Side note: You wouldn't say that you "give products on rent". You can say, "We offer products for rent", "We have products available for rent", or "We rent products". (The last is ambiguous, as both the person offering the product and the person paying for it are said to "rent" it. "I am renting a house" could mean that you own a house that you are charging someone else to live in, or that you are paying to live in a house that belongs to someone else.)

Answer (score 0):

**'Shop'** and **'Rent'** are two totally different things. 
In shopping, you generally take ownership of a product after you purchase it, in exchange of money. Whereas, *"To rent"* means to lease out something for a particular period of time, and must be returned thereafter. So if it is for rent, I wouldn't use shop. Might I suggest an alternate word you could use ?

> **Checkout**

This is widely used in many e-Shopping sites. Although [Checkout](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=check+out+meaning&oq=check+out&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.2831j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=checkout+meaning) literally means :

> a point at which goods are paid for in a supermarket or similar store

It can be used for renting out a product too. Checking out (something) means that you're approving of taking its ownership, and taking it out of the place of purchase, under your authority. So maybe you could replace the word *"Shop Now"* with **"Checkout"**. In my opinion, there are very few words you could use that would sound okay in terms of both "purchasing" and "renting", and I'm only aware of this word.

Comment: *Checkout* happens **once** you select the items and ready to pay. That's **not** the case here. Here, clicking on the button *takes* us to the ski products available for **rent**. Yes, but if I play a bit more, I can 'split' it and **then** it may make sense - 'check out' instead of 'checkout!' :)

Comment: Originally I wrote _"Check Out"_, but that has various other meanings when I googled it. Do you think _"Check Out"_ is a better option ?

Comment: Of course...in fact it's not better option because those two words are *entirely* different! 'Check out' means 'look for/see that' and 'checkout' means 'shopping done, ready to pay'.